# commerce cart block with drupal theme

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I want to overwrite the block generated template drupal commerce "commerce cart" using the bootstrap theme.
What I need is the name with which overwrite block.tpl.php theme for that specific block bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Edit your cart view and under Advanced, Theming: Information, click on Information and you will see this:

[image]

For template file name you want to use the last suggested name, (which I underlined for you) that way it only affects this specific view and not others.

Now that you have a name, click on the blue link and copy all the code in there and paste it into your template file and modify as you wish.

Remember to flush the cache to see changes or you could click the <kbd>Rescan template files</kbd> button

Comment: thanks, but I want to override is the template block containing the view not the template view

Comment: @Marco.M notice how the first 3 options template names end in `--block`. The view itself is a block. You probably want to use the first one `views-view--shopping-cart--block.tpl.php`